# Only one data are displaying dbref.push().setValue().addOnCompleteListener

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, datetime, qr-code

```
public void handleResult(Result result) {
        String data = result.getText().toString();
        Date dateAndTime = (Date) Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        String date = dateFormat.format(dateAndTime);
        String time = timeFormat.format(dateAndTime);

        StoreInfo storeInfo = new StoreInfo(data, date, time);

        dbref.push().setValue(storeInfo).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                scanner.qrtext.setText("Course: " + data);
                scanner.date.setText("Date: " + date);
                scanner.arrival.setText("Arrival time: " + time);
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
    }
```

If I change the `dbref.push().setValue(data)` only 1 data are storing in firebase, but when I change it to  `dbref.push().setValue(storeInfo)`, nothing is saving.

I expect to store the data of qr, date, and time.

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you try to write an object of type `StoreInfo` to the Realtime Database?

Comment: No, but nothing is displaying. @AlexMamo

Comment: Have you tried to see what happens when the task is not successful?

Comment: You need to grab the ```key``` first while doing the push before ```setValue``` like this: ```String key = dbref.push().getKey();
dbref.child(key).setValue(storeInfo);```